# Is there a term for the activity of weightless astronauts hanging out on walls or ceilings?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, microgravity, terminology, astronaut-lifestyle

Weightless astronauts often sit, stand, walk, or sleep on (or near) surfaces that (with gravity) we would normally call walls or ceilings.  I reference such a phenomenon in my comment [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35869/which-module-had-more-comfort-in-terms-of-living-space-the-lunar-module-or-th/35870#comment113896_35870):

> I would also add that the bulk of the CSM flight was in weightlessness, which allows astronauts to reside in places and orientations that are not otherwise convenient. (Shuttle astronauts also took advantage of this.)

Is there an accepted name or jargon for this activity?

Comment: It's called being weightless....

Comment: It's not an _ability_ of the astronauts.  It's a _disability_ of those observers whose minds insist on seeing surfaces as walls and ceilings, terms that have no meaning in those situations.

Comment: @RayButterworth the Space Shuttle cockpit had clearly defined floors,  walls and ceilings, regardless of whether it was on the pad, on the ground, or in free-fall.  Moving the vehicle to different places doesn't change the names of the inner structure parts.

Comment: @RayButterworth have a look at [When reading “the writing on the wall” in the ISS, which way is up?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34199/12102) and its answer.

Comment: Anecdotally, I _have_ heard long duration crew refer to the act of moving from one place to another by using the verb "to fly."  Can't remember any unusual terms being used to describe hanging out...

Comment: You're weightless.  What's a ceiling?